# Could AutoMapper Help Here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am developing an ASP.Net Web API. I have an entity named `Task`. Creating a new Task is achieved using a static factory method to ensure some checks are made prior to creation. The `Task` setters are private ensuring changes are made using the public methods I expose.

I have created a `TaskViewModel` class with simple public properties matching those of the `Task` entity.

My `TaskController`'s `HttpPost` method takes the values from the Post request body and maps them to the `TaskViewModel` properties:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]TaskViewModel task)
{
    ...
}
```

So now I have a `task` object containing all of the values I require to create a new `Task` object. To do this I call `Task.CreateTask(...)` manually passing in and matching each parameter in the `CreateTask` method.

Can AutoMapper be used to simplify this process. I am aware that it could map the values across from the `TaskViewModel` to the `Task`, but am unsure if it could help in this scenario?

Comment: Can you pass the TaskViewModel as Argument to Task.CreateTask and then map it with Automapper inside CreateTask to a Task?

Comment: It's an interesting idea but I want to keep my `CreateTask` method clean as it will be used in other scenarios.

Comment: There is an alternative hacky way... With C# you are able to get the Information about Parameters and the Task object over the Reflection API and you should be able to call the Method dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

AM can map using private setters. It can also map to constructor parameters (the constructors can be private), but not to any method's parameters.
You can tell AM (by calling ConstructUsing) to use that method when creating a new instance, but to avoid copying the parameters you would need to make that method receive the source class or some member of the source class. A compromise approach would be to map to a private constructor and have the factory method call that same constructor.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#configuring-visibility

Comment: I'm grateful for your contributions to [so]; nevertheless, please use a comment if you don't have time to give a complete answer. Since your post is already here, why don't you add a code example and explain how it works?

Comment: There is nothing special about private setters. It just works.

Comment: I want to continue to use the `CreateTask` method for the reason I created it in the first place, to protect against invalid values. I didn't know if there was any way of mapping to the parameters of the method.